# Prove by induction $f(x)=x\ln x,x>0$ and $n\in N$. Prove if $n\ge 3$, then $f^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^n[(n-2)!/x^{n-1}]$

Tags: calculus, induction

$f(x)=x\ln x, x>0$ and $n\in N$. Let $f^{(n)}(x)$ denote the $n$th derivative. Prove if $n\ge 3$, then $f^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^n[(n-2)!/x^{n-1}]$

I don't understand the solution after it does the base case of $n=3$ then it assumes this statement is true for $n=m$ and that $f^{(m)}(x)=(-1)^m[(m-2)!/x^{m-1}]$

Thus,
$f^{(m+1)}(x)=df^{(m)}/dx=(-1)^m(1-m)[(m-2)!/x^m]=(-1)^{m+1}[(m-1)!/x^m]$

I'm confused how they got $(-1)^{m+1}$ on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They factored $-1$ from the $(1-m)$ to get $(-1)(m-1)$ and then used the fact that $(m-1)(m-2)! = (m-1)!$

Comment: o really? Okay now I'm confused where they get $1-m$ from. I thought they got $(1-m)$ from the derivative of $x^m$, but now I don't know.

Comment: They are taking the derivative with respect to $x$ of $f^{(m)}$ and by the induction hypothesis, that is equal to the derivative of $(−1)^m\frac{(m−2)!}{x^{(m−1)}}$. Try taking the derivative of that. The $(-1)^m(m-2)!$ term is treated as constant so you are left with the derivative of $\frac{1}{x^{(m-1)}}$. That's where the $(1-m)$ term comes from.

Comment: that would be (m-2) no?

Comment: Not quite, you will also pick up a negative since the $x^{(m-1)}$ term is in the denominator (quotient rule).

Comment: ahhh I see makes sense. Sorry I meant $(m-1)$, but I see what you mean now.